# How to set the default value and read the selected value of a Dropdown Listbox

Tags: abap, dynpro

So I've added a field with the Dropdown type as Listbox via Screen Painter (SE51).

I've binded the data to the dropdown using the PBO and the **VRM_SET_VALUES** function.

[image]

I have 2 problems with this;

1. How do you set a selected value to the binded data?
2. How do you get the value selected by the user.

Data is bound to the dropdown using the following code;

```
LOOP AT it_zzdelay_text INTO wa_zzdelay_text.
  wa_listbox-key = wa_zzdelay_text-zz_delay_reason.
  wa_listbox-text = wa_zzdelay_text-zz_delay_reason_text.
  APPEND wa_listbox TO it_listbox.
ENDLOOP.

 CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
  EXPORTING
    id     = 'ZZ_DELAY_REASON'
    values = it_listbox.
```

The **zz_delay_reason** is the unique key and the **zz_delay_reason_text** is the accompanying text.

Comment: Just use the variable used to define the screen field...? We won't be able to give any more advice without some code...

Comment: @vwegert ay thoughts? I had to resort to creating a search help to workaround this. Want to make it right by properly implementing a dropdown controller

Comment: Main thought right now: "Provide a COMPLETE example and not just some random code snippets." I have neither the time nor the energy to engage in elaborate guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

According to your code, the field on the screen should be: ZZ_DELAY_REASON
And you also need a global variant with the name.

Then you can Set/Get key value in PBO/PAI:
Set value:
ZZ_DELAY_REASON = 'KEY'.

Get Selected Value(key):
lv_key = ZZ_DELAY_REASON

======================================================

When select list is set by VRM_SET_VALUES, you may notice it is a "Key-Value" pair. The field "KEY" is filled into the screen field value when the user selects drop box.

I could provide detailed information if you attach your code in this question.

Comment: hi @terence4444, i've added the code used to bind the data to the dropdown controller.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, several prerequisites are to be met to make a functional drop-down:

1. You item table should have type `vrm_values`
2. Values that are showed in the list should be in field `text` of the item line. Key should be in field `key`.
3. PARAMETER should have type `LISTBOX`.

After all that is done, answers for your questions would be:

1. Relation of KEY-VALUE is done via `vrm_values` type. Each line of this type is an drop-down item, where `text` is a visible text, and `key` is key.
2. Parameter automatically gets the key value after user selects the item in the listbox.

Here is the sample code:

```
REPORT drop-down.

TYPE-POOLS: vrm.

PARAMETERS p_werks LIKE t001w-werks VISIBLE LENGTH 20 AS LISTBOX OBLIGATORY.

DATA: t_werks TYPE vrm_values,
w_line LIKE LINE OF t_werks.

INITIALIZATION.

SELECT werks name1
  FROM t001w INTO (w_line-key, w_line-text).
APPEND w_line TO t_werks.
ENDSELECT.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.

CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
EXPORTING
id = 'P_WERKS'
values = t_werks.

END-OF-SELECTION.

WRITE: / 'Selected factory:', p_werks.
```